# Using go modules with a typical directory structure, can't seem to get it working

Tags: go

So I created a simple test project to demonstrate the issue I'm having in a much larger code base here https://github.com/cleblanc189/test.go

```
.
├── go.mod
├── main.exe
├── main.go
├── server
│   ├── v1beta1
│   │   ├── foo.go
│   │   └── go.mod
│   └── v1ga
│       ├── foo.go
│       └── go.mod
└── service
    ├── v1beta1
    │   ├── foo.go
    │   └── go.mod
    └── v1ga
        ├── foo.go
        └── go.mod
```

I'd like to be able to reference service/v1beta1 from server/v1beta1 but I'm getting this error

```
go: test.go/src/server/v1beta1@v0.0.0 requires
        test.go/src/service/v1beta1@v0.0.0: unrecognized import path "test.go/src/service/v1beta1" (https fetch: Get https://test.go/src/ser
vice/v1beta1?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup test.go: no such host)
```

In foo.go from server/v1beta1 I import like this
`svc "test.go/src/service/v1beta1"`

and have a go.mod file like below;

```
require test.go/src/service/v1beta1 v0.0.0

replace test.go/src/service/v1beta1 => ../../service/v1beta1
```

When I try to `cd src && go mod tidy` I get that error above.  Also if anyone knows should I even have a go.mod above the src directory?

Appreciate any help anyone can offer.  This is maddening.

Comment: Are you sure you need all of those to be separate modules and not just packages in one module? This is an extremely unusual setup as shown.

Comment: At least the  src path in your import path is at least unidomatic and probably wrong. Also: import paths begin with the module name which you did not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `go.mod` has to declare the module path/name, typically like this:

```
module test.go
```

Then all the `import`s in your code will be taken relative to that. When you import something relative to your declared module name, the `go` tool will automatically pick up the code from the right place locally.

Not sure where your `src` comes into play though... is everything in folder `src`? See [this post and accompanying code](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/simple-go-project-layout-with-modules/) for a complete example you could start from.

Comment: Thanks.  I got the wrong idea from the wiki here https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem which states "Note: if the right-hand side of a replace directive is a filesystem path, then the target must have a go.mod file at that location."